# Ajax PUT dataType issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, put

Hey guys im having a stupid problem with ajax PUT, after i try put the json data back the server thinks its xml data even though i use: dataType: "application/json", any idea why this may he happening? This is how my PUT looks:

```
$.ajax({ 
type: "PUT", 
url: bank_url, 
dataType: "application/json", 
data: {"banking_detail_id": page.viewModel.payer_banking_detail_id(),
 "person_id": person_id, "account_number": page.viewModel.payer_account_number(),
 "branch": page.viewModel.payer_branch(), "date_inserted": page.viewModel.payer_date_insterted(),
 "date_effective": page.viewModel.payer_date_effective(), "account_type": page.viewModel.payer_account_type(),
 "account_holder": page.viewModel.payer_account_holder() , "debit_day": page.viewModel.payer_debit_day() ,
 "branch_code": page.viewModel.payer_branch_code() , "bank_branch_id": page.viewModel.payer_bank_branch_id(),
 "branch_name": page.viewModel.payer_branch_name(), "bank_name": page.viewModel.payer_bank_name(),
 "user_id": page.viewModel.payer_user_id()}, 
});
```

The server responds like this:

> xhr =
>   {"length":847,"name":"error","severity":"ERROR","code":"23502","detail":"Failing
>   row contains (null, 1081563, 12341234, ABSA ELECTRONIC SETTLEMENT CNT
>   (632005), 2013-05-05 00:00:00, 2013-05-06, 0, Coetzee M A, 1, null,
>   0).","where":"SQL statement \"INSERT INTO banking_detail(
>   \n\t\t\t\tbanking_detail_id, \n\t\t\t\tperson_id,
>   \n\t\t\t\taccount_number, \n\t\t\t\tbranch, \n\t\t\t\tdate_inserted,
>   \n\t\t\t\tdate_effective, \n\t\t\t\taccount_type,
>   \n\t\t\t\taccount_holder, \n\t\t\t\tdebit_day,
>   \n\t\t\t\tbank_branch_id, \n\t\t\t\tuser_id)\n\t\t\tVALUES (
>   \n\t\t\t\tnew.banking_detail_id,\n\t\t\t\tnew.person_id,\n\t\t\t\tnew.account_number,\n\t\t\t\tnew.branch,\n\t\t\t\tnew.date_inserted,\n\t\t\t\tnew.date_effective,\n\t\t\t\tnew.account_type,\n\t\t\t\tnew.account_holder,\n\t\t\t\tnew.debit_day,\n\t\t\t\tnew.bank_branch_id,\n\t\t\t\tnew.user_id)\"\nPL/pgSQL
>   function banking_detail_view_set() line 4 at SQL
>   statement","file":"execMain.c","line":"1527","routine":"ExecConstraints"}

Comment: What exactly is the response generated by the server? Does it include `xhr = `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

request type is GET or POST 
ex :

```
    type: "GET", 
    type: "POST",
```

and dataType is xml, json, script, or html
ex:

```
    dataType:'html',
    dataType:'xml',
    dataType:'json',
    dataType:'script',
```

Comment: Yeah sorry guys I didn't include the primary key :P

Comment: All major browsers also support PUT and DELETE.

Comment: nice copy-paste from the internet, but you've forgot type `text` also